# Seems impossible to control Apache Httpd server in windows

Tags: apache-2.2, windows

I need to start and stop apache as a normal process (not as service) without a console or window.
I tried

```
start "" /b httpd.exe
```

And It works, but how to stop it? Maybe only with taskkill /f, but this seems to be not a good stopping.
I can not use httpd -k start because I want to start apache also in normal user mode and not only with administrator user.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short of somply closing the window or Ctrl-C, like you've said, Taskkill should work, as shown in the answer below:

[How can I kill the Apache service on a Windows server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/361690/how-can-i-kill-the-apache-service-on-a-windows-server?rq=1)

> TASKKILL /F /IM httpd.exe /T

It won't exactly be a clean shutdown of Apache like httpd -k would but will stop the process.

You can also use PSKILL from PSTOOLS, but it really accomplishes the same thing.

But overall, why run it without a service?  It would be much easier to control correctly.

Comment: I agree with you but I need this just few times than I don't want to leave the service up all the time. Moreove I want to run it as normal user.

Comment: /F and /T are not opposite? Something like TERM vs KILL?

Comment: /F will force it closed.  You can try it without /F first to see if it will gracefully close Apache.  /T will close it and any child processes it has spawned.

Comment: So /T kills also the second "httpd" process?